# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "wer" und "der" ? nebensatz

Tags: difference, grammaticality

> der Mann ist mein Cousin , der keine Spageti mag 
> der Mann ist mein Cousin , wer keine Spageti mag

gibt es unterschied wenn man wer oder der benutzt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richtig ist im Hochdeutschen nur die erste Variante mit dem Relativpronomen 'der'. Üblicherweise folgt der Relativsatz aber dem Satzteil auf den er sich bezieht, hier dem Subjekt 'der Mann'.
Dann ist die geläufigere Satzkonstruktion von den genannten Sätzen leicht verschieden mit eingeschobenem Relativsatz, da dieser sich auf das Subjekt des Satzes bezieht. Verständlich ist die von Dir genannte Satzstellung mit dem Relativsatz am Ende hier aber auch, da es sich bei "mein Cousin" in diesem Fall um einen Gleichsetzungsnominativ (Nominativ-Objekt) handelt:

> Der Mann, der keine Spaghetti mag, ist mein Cousin.

Umgangssprachlich wird manchmal das Relativpronomen 'der' oder 'welcher' durch 'wer' ersetzt.

> Der Mann, welcher/wer keine Spaghetti mag, ist mein Cousin.

Comment: Je nach Position des Relativsatzes ist die Bedeutung eine andere. Bei dir: Hier sind mehrere Männer. Einer von ihnen mag keine Spaghetti, und dieser ist mein Cousin. Oder: Ich habe von einem Mann erzählt, der keine Spaghetti mag. Das ist mein Cousin. In der Frage: Hier ist ein Mann. Es ist mein Cousin, und der mag keine Spaghetti.

Comment: Wo benutzt man denn "wer" als Relativpronomen? Klingt für mich nur falsch und nicht nach Dialekt.

Comment: @CarstenS gehört habe ich es sowohl in Niedersachsen als auch Thüringen - aber wie gesagt selten (darum 'manchmal').

Comment: Interessant, Danke.